# How can I look up my monitor's native resolution in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, display-resolution, monitor

I thought this detail would be in the Info Center, but the only similar info I can find there (under Graphical Information -> X Server) is just showing the *current* resolution, not the details on what the hardware supports.

The reason I need this is because I was trying out a game (Berusky) and it set my monitor resolution extremely low, and didn't reset it when exiting.  I know my native resolution is either 1366x768 or 1360x768, but the difference is small enough (six pixels) that I can't tell visually which one is "correct."  (The monitor is my built-in laptop monitor, by the way.)

Where is this information available?  I would like to know how to find it both via the GUI, and via the command line, if that is possible.

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 which I know is not supported yet, but I would accept answers that only apply to 19.10.  (I would be surprised if the methods for finding out this info have changed, anyway.)

Obviously I can search the internet for my particular model of hardware and look up the specs that way, but I would like to know how to do this "inside" the OS if at all possible.

Comment: I have just one monitor, my laptop! I have `inxi` installed. And `inxi -Gxxz` has, among other things, `Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: intel compositor: kwin_x11 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
`. There maybe other ways as well. One is `xwininfo -root` (with `-root`, not `--root`). If you have `neofetch`, then `neofetch --stdout` will also mention the resolution.

Comment: `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep Geometry` is there as well. But I don't know how any of these work when there's more than one monitor. On my Tumblweed VM, I need to use `qdbus-qt5`, not plain `qdbus`. I'll check my Kubuntu 20.04 VM later but I think it still will use just `qdbus`.

Comment: @DKBose, sorry I wasn't clear; it IS my laptop monitor!  I've edited that info into my question.  (Although I do have a nice 4K monitor that I use with my other computer, I haven't used it with my Linux laptop--yet.)

Comment: @DKBose, using `inxi -Gxxz` produces different results after changing the resolution.  In other words, it appears to reflect only the *current* resolution, like the Info Center.  Ditto for `xwininfo -root` and ditto for `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation | grep Geometry`.  I don't have neofetch.

Comment: Hmmm... Then the alternative you mentioned of looking up the specs maybe the only way. One more possibility is *System Settings > Display & Monitors*. It has a *Default* button and a list of resolutions it knows about. Any luck there?

Comment: @DKBose thanks!  Oddly, there was a defaults button when I first opened it, but it was greyed out.  On the chance that I might already be at the default setting (1366), I changed it to 1360, and now the defaults button is gone and won't come back no matter what I try (including changing back to 1366).  Bizarre; I'll just DuckDuckGo my laptop model for now and leave this question for a possible future answer.

Answer (score 4):

Technically every monitor has special I2C device, from where [Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) can be read.

You can install the `read-edid` package and check the manufacturer's data inside the panel with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install read-edid
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

Example: for my 1366x768 I get the following output (it is really single line, as there are no other modes):

> ...
>   `` Modeline     "Mode 0" 77.00 1366 1424 1460 1560 768 771 778 822 -hsync -vsync` ``

For external monitors these commands return more data. Something like:

> ...
>    `#Not giving standard mode: 1920x1200, 60Hz`

About ModeLines you can read [on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr) if interested.